# How can the Determinant of a square matrix be written as an integral?

Tags: integration, determinant, string-theory

## Context

I am working through Polchinski's book on string theory (Volume 1 on the bosonic string). In his exercise question 3.5, one has to show how a gauge invariant action multiplied by a gauge invariant insertion, can be re-expressed as an integral of the original action, a gauge fixing action, and the Faddeev-Popov action over a functional. There is a solution manual (http://arXiv.org/abs/0812.4408v1), where this question is answered. However, in one step (equation 24 in the solutions maual), a relation between the determinant of a non-singular square matrix and an integral is used that I haven't seen before.

## Question

Is the following true, and if so, why?

$$
\text{det}\left(\partial_\phi F^A\right)=\left(\int\!\left[\mathrm{d}\epsilon^B\right]\partial_\phi F^A\partial_{\epsilon^B}\phi\right)^{-1}
$$

with the integrand being a non-singular square matrix and $\phi$ a field.

Comment: Title question: for example by $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x \cdot A x} dx = \sqrt{\frac{(2\pi)^n}{\det{A}}}$$